# Flutter BUILD FAILED for iOS-for Map View(works for android)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

When I ran `flutter run` command this error appeared.

I am trying to use a `map_view`.

My Xcode version is 9.2

In file included from

> /Users/rsaivenkatesh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/map_view-0.0.10/ios/Classes/MapViewPlugin.m:1:
>   /Users/rsaivenkatesh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/map_view-0.0.10/ios/Classes/MapViewPlugin.h:1:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
>    #import
>
> 1 error generated.
>   Could not build the application for the simulator.
>   Error launching application on iPhone X.

Comment: I think you should upgrade to a newer Flutter version `flutter channel dev` `flutter doctor` `flutter update-packages --force-upgrade`

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer No I am still getting the same error .This happens only if I add the dependency map_view 0.0.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem trying to include the audioplayer package

> audioplayer-0.4.0/ios/Classes/AudioplayerPlugin.h:1:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

I thought I was up-to-date, but after I did a Flutter upgrade and then deleted Podfile, Podfile.lock and the Pods folder from my ios directory under my project (and ran flutter clean), I was finally able to build and launch to iOS. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/16273

I'm using Xcode 9.3 and Cocoapods 1.5.0
Flutter shows version 0.3.1 after upgrading.

Comment: Thanks, deleting all that pod stuff is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to `flutter pub upgrade` to make sure you have the latest dependencies.

Comment: Tried that but still getting the same error.
Do you have any other solutions?